# Cannot run .exe file after compiler a c++ file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I use VSC to make a simple hello work c++. Then I use "g++ c.cpp -o c" to compile, but I cannot run the c.exe file by command "c.exe". I remember I could run c++ before in the same way. Do I miss anything? Could you help me please?

[image]

Comment: In the future, please copy the actual error message into your question instead of the screenshot. That will enable other people who have the same issue to be able to successfully search for it.

Comment: What is VSC? You're using a Linux compiler to produce an executable, which looks like it may be a Windows executable? If this were Linux your executable filename would be called just 'c' .?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `c.exe` is there.

Since you are using PowerShell, you need to run local files with a `.\` prefix, e.g. `.\c.exe`